# Array access is not allowed on List<Int>

Tags: arrays, list, compiler-errors, haxe

I'm actually french student in IT Programmation my project is o make the battleship game and when i wrote the function AI Turn it tells me an error how can i stop this error?
here is the code of the function :

```
private function tourIA(){

    var position = new List<Int>();
    for(i in 0...(Std.parseInt(Math.pow(dimensions,2)))position.add(i);

    var pos = Std.random(length(position);
    var cellule = position[pos];
    var x = cellule%dimensions;
    var y = Math.floor(cellule);
    var n : Navire = mer.chercherNavire(x , y);
    if (n != null) {
        mer.montrerNavire(n);
    }
    else{
        mer.placerCroix(mer, position, dimension);
    }
}
```

The error is on `var cellule = position[pos];`

Answer (score 5):

[`List`](https://api.haxe.org/List.html) is a linked list and does not allow arbitrary access at a specific index - you'd have to iterate over it to find the element you're looking for, which is not very efficient. I'd recommend to use an [`Array`](https://api.haxe.org/Array.html) instead:

```
var positions = [];
for (i in 0...Std.int(Math.pow(dimensions, 2)))
    positions.push(i);

var pos = Std.random(positions.length);
var cellule = positions[pos];
// ...
```

However, in this specific case, it seems like you need neither a `List` nor an `Array` - you could just calculate `cellule` like this since the array elements are just strictly incremented (`[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]` - or perhaps there's a mistake there and it should be something like `[0, 1, 4, 9, ...]`?):

```
var cellule = Std.random(Math.pow(dimensions, 2));
```